# Access Animated.Value from React context

Tags: react-native

I use ReactContext and now i would like to keep `Animated.Value` in context itself. So, any components that will use this context would be able to access this `Animated.Value`.

I have few `ScrollView` components that's updating my `Animated.Value` and based on that, i would like to have some animations.

**Problem:** My animations in components, that use this `Animated.Value` from Context never work. Whenever i add `addListener` to animation i see that value being change, but animations doesnt work when i use `interpolate` or something else.

Here is part of code that updates my `scrollY` value on scroll

```
onScroll={Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: context.scrollY } } }], { useNativeDriver: true })}
```

Here is my simple interpolation

```
const translateY = context.scrollY.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, DISTANCE],
      outputRange: [MAX_HEIGHT, MIN_HEIGHT],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    });
```

Here is where this transform applied:

```
<Animated.View style={[styles.container, { transform: [{translateY }] }, styles.header]}>
```

Did i miss something? Is that even possible to achieve that?